# Is there an efficient way to iterate over Pandas DataFrame chunks?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, apply

### Original Post

I am working with time series data and I want to apply a function to each data frame chunk for rolling time intervals/windows. When I use `rolling()` and `apply()` on a Pandas DataFrame, it applies the function iteratively for each column given a time interval. Here's example code:

- Sample data

In:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
                'B': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]}, 
                index=pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=6, freq='5T'))
print(df)
```

Out:

```
                     A   B
2019-01-01 00:00:00  1   2
2019-01-01 00:05:00  2   4
2019-01-01 00:10:00  3   6
2019-01-01 00:15:00  4   8
2019-01-01 00:20:00  5  10
2019-01-01 00:25:00  6  12
```

- Output when using the combination of rolling() and apply():

In:

```
print(df.rolling('15T', min_periods=2).apply(lambda x: x.sum().sum()))
```

Out:

```
                        A     B
2019-01-01 00:00:00   NaN   NaN
2019-01-01 00:05:00   3.0   6.0
2019-01-01 00:10:00   6.0  12.0
2019-01-01 00:15:00   9.0  18.0
2019-01-01 00:20:00  12.0  24.0
2019-01-01 00:25:00  15.0  30.0
```

Desired Out:

```
2019-01-01 00:00:00     NaN
2019-01-01 00:05:00     9.0
2019-01-01 00:10:00    18.0
2019-01-01 00:15:00    27.0
2019-01-01 00:20:00    36.0
2019-01-01 00:25:00    45.0
Freq: 5T, dtype: float64
```

Currently, I am using a for loop to do the job, but I am looking for a more efficient way to handle this operation. I would appreciate it if you can provide a solution within the Pandas framework or even with other libraries.

**Note:** *Please do not take the example function (summation) seriously, assume that the function in interest requires iterating over the chunks of datasets as is, i.e., with no prior column operations.*

Thanks in advance!

### Edit/Update

After reading the responses I have realized that the example I have given was not adequate. Here I go again using the same sample data:

In:

```
print(
    df.rolling('15T', min_periods=2).apply(
        lambda x: x['A'].mean() / x['B'].std()
    )
)
```

Out:

```
KeyError: 'A'
```

Desired Out:

```
2019-01-01 00:00:00    NaN
2019-01-01 00:05:00   1.06
2019-01-01 00:10:00   1.00
2019-01-01 00:15:00   1.50
2019-01-01 00:20:00   2.00
2019-01-01 00:25:00   2.50
Freq: 5T, dtype: float64
```

Again, I want to point out that the main objective of my question is to find an efficient way to iterate over chunks of dataframes. For example, I do not want the following solution.

```
df['A'].rolling('15T', min_periods=2).mean() / df['B'].rolling('15T', min_periods=2).std()
```

And, for those who are interested in the real problem rather than the simple example, you can check it out here at [mlfactor](https://www.mlfactor.com/Data.html?q=trip#the-triple-barrier-method) where **triple barrier method** is explained.

Comment: `df.rolling('15T', min_periods=2).sum().sum(axis=1)` would be faster.

Comment: Also, if your data is 5 mins apart, you can roll by 3 rows, faster than rolling by 15T.

Comment: @QuangHoang, I tried to explain at the end of the post, the example function is simply there to illustrate the problem. In my use case, my function can not be reduced to any other form and quite more complicated.

Comment: The general mindset of Pandas is to not iterate, e.g. `apply` in this case. If you cannot rewrite your function into Pandas core functions as you mentioned, then Pandas offers no other improvement aside from the `rolling` that extracts the sub-dataframes for you.

Comment: Are you trying to roll a little dataframe into another one ?